# random-acess machine (RAM) - Test square-free n

Tags: complexity-theory

I'm writing a random-acess machine (RAM) using a simulator that tests whether a given natural number is square-free. My goal is to then analyze its complexity.

At high-level I would use the following test function

```
def isSquareFree(n):

    if n % 2 == 0:
        n = n / 2

    if n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    for i in range(3, int(sqrt(n) + 1)):
        if n % i == 0:
            n = n / i

        if n % i == 0:
            return False

return True
```

My problem is, I am not sure how to calculate the square root of n using RAM-commands and can't find much resources online. So I am reconsidering if this is actually the right way to do it.

What are alternative ways to test if a natural number is square-free, that can be implemented using RAM?

Thanks.

Comment: As it's currently written, this quest is very broad. I recommend you limit this question to a specific piece of your problem. For example, "How to calculate square root on RAM?", or "What are alternative ways to test square free?". Additionally, requests for off-site resources are explicitly off-topic and may result in your question being ignored or closed

Comment: Thanks. Edited now.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to avoid the `sqrt` in your code you can simply test for `i*i<=n`. This probably is a good idea anywise, as calculating the square root is a quite hard thing to do.

Thus I would change your code to:

```
def isSquareFree(n):
    i=2   
    while i*i <= n:
        if n % i == 0:
            n = n / i

        if n % i == 0:
            return False
        
        i = i+1

    return True
```

The above only uses pretty atomic operations, so I hope this will help you. But I am not familiar with RAM programming so I am not sure whether this solves your problem.